# Getting last 24 hours data from MySQL in PHP with custom date string

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, time

I'm adding a custom date string to the database by using;

```
$date = date("H:i:sa | d-m-Y");
$sql = "INSERT INTO data
        (artist, title, presenter, timeplayed)
        VALUES('$artist','$title','$presenter','$date')";
```

However I can't then quite figure out how to get $date back out but only the last 24 hours worth of entries. So between 00:00:00 yesterday and 23:59:59 today.

I've tried:

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE timeplayed > DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
```

And similar,  however it's bringing back data older than 24 hours.

I'm storing the data in timeplayed as varchar. I wonder if that's the reason?

Comment: Why are you storing the date in a non-standard format? You should be doing the formatting at the presentation layer and let MySQL handle dates how it was meant to.

Comment: I don't think you can compare you custom data string to a normal data

Comment: And now you know why storing dates as a non-standard format string is a bad idea

Comment: @RobM. Because I couldn't figure out formatting at the presentation layer and I was rushing ... Looks like it's biting me on the bum and I should probably look at that part instead eh...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per above comments you should save the data as proper mysql date format and to get the data of last 24 hours you can use the inerval of day subtracting from `NOW()`

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE timeplayed >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should rethink your approach. All of the `Date` functions in MySQL are geared toward the formats it expects. It would be much easier to do this in the presentation layer as:

`echo date('H:i:sa | d-m-Y', strtotime($row['timeplayed']);`

This will allow you to use all of the MySQL functions as expected.

Comment: OK - I've changed it to be datetime in MySQL and now inserting with now() which is working great. Just need to get this bit working.

Currently doing;

`foreach($row1 as $key=>$value) {
     echo '<td>',$value,'</td>';
    }`

Any thoughts? :/

Comment: Replace your commas with periods and you should be good to go: `foreach($row1 as $key=>$value) { echo '<td>'.$value.'</td>'; }`

Comment: Sorry - Was meant to say I'm doing `while($row1 = mysql_fetch_row($result2)) {` then the foreach. So failing to work out what to do with the date & strtotime! Can you tell I'm slightly new? :)

Comment: `if($key == 'timeplayed'){ echo '<td>'.date('H:i:sa | d-m-Y', strtotime($value['timeplayed'])).'</td>'; }` in your `foreach`. No worries, we were all new at one time or another :)

Comment: Thanks for that. I was along them lines but weirdly it's doing the first column in the table and not the actual timeplayed column, even after saying else perform the usual $value (and funkily converting text to time! lol). Getting there!

Comment: `foreach` doesn't necessarily iterate in "order", if you need things to go in a particular order use a `for` loop instead. Glad you are getting closer with your project though :)

Comment: Ah OK - I will look at that next then. Appreciate your help, thank you! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Why not try:

```
$from_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("2013-12-11"))." 00:00:00";
$to_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("2013-12-12")." 11:59:59";

select * from data where timeplayed <= $to_date and timeplayed >= $from_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to the custom date, your only savior is this query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE timeplayed LIKE '%".date("d-m-Y")."'";
```

This will yield horrid performance as your table grows...